# how are actions defined in OData V3 metadata?

Tags: odata

Hi i'm create a code generation tool for Odata, so far the odata v4 have been really simple to implement.

Regarding odata V3 i have been having troubles with the metadata because I don't know where actions are defined so far I have been only able to see FunctionImport on metadata but not actions, are FunctionImport an equivalent to actions for OData V3? if not can you point on which node of the metadata are the actions located ?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Actions can be bound or unbound and can be added to the metadata(EDM) as follows:

```
builder.Entity<entityname>.Action("actionname").Parameter<type>("paramtername").Returns<type>();
```

Here, builder can be either ODataBuilder or ConventionalOdataBuilder.
If you want the action to be unbound, you can remove the Entity and directly add it to the builder.
If you wish to add the action to IEdmModel directly, you can add the action as a schemaelement.

Source:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v3/odata-actions

Edit: Actions are defined in metadata as follows:

```
<Schema Namespace="Default" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm">
<EntityContainer Name="Container" m:IsDefaultEntityContainer="true">
 <EntitySet Name="Movies" EntityType="ODataActionsSample.Models.Movie" />
  <FunctionImport Name="SetDueDate" ReturnType="ODataActionsSample.Models.Movie" IsBindable="true" EntitySet="Movies" m:IsAlwaysBindable="true">                    
    <Parameter Name="bindingParameter" Type="ODataActionsSample.Models.Movie" />                    
    <Parameter Name="DueDate" Type="Edm.DateTime" Nullable="false" />       
  </FunctionImport>
  <FunctionImport Name="CreateMovie" ReturnType="ODataActionsSample.Models.Movie" EntitySet="Movies">
    <Parameter Name="Title" Type="Edm.String" FixedLength="false" Unicode="false" />
  </FunctionImport>
</EntityContainer>
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, it partially answer my question, now I understand how you add actions you your metadata, but what I really want to see is a metadata example V3  where the actions are defined in the xml. Right now I'm casting the metdata to IEdmModel and reading all the info I need from there

Comment: The metadata is retrieved in the form of XML in the response. While in the code you can retrieve it in IEdmModel. You need not cast the metadata to IEdmModel, builder.GetEdmModel() does that for you.
If you are asking for building Edm manually without any associated models, then this link might help you out:
http://odata.github.io/WebApi/ (in actions under 2.2.Build Edm Model Explicitly)

Comment: Thanks again for your answer, you need to remember that I'm not building the metadata, im reading it from a third party service so basically im downloading the XML and parsing it to generate POCO classes to query the service, I would also like to generate the functions and actions, i have not see any OdataV3 service 3 that contains actions thats why I dont know how they look like in the metadata or the xml

Comment: Sorry for misinterpreting your question, in Odata v3 actions are defined as functionimport as you have said earlier. The following segment might help you on how actions are defined in metadata. Here "SetDueDate" is a bound action where as "CreateMovie" is an unbound action.